# Does YouTube favor some users' comments more than others

Tags: youtube

it doesn't take much time on YouTube scrolling through the comments to find someone writing a comment and barely being noticed, and someone else copies his comment and gets all the attention and even loads of likes, or those certain accounts that have their comments always on top, ignoring YouTube's broken "top comments", those users might be above others with thousands of likes! I'd like to know why, why would YouTube favor some users on others, I've done my research and heard that YouTube makes your comments appear more the more you post comments, but it doesn't seem plausible to and it wasn't from a site you could trust because I've never seen someone else say that, other than that I've failed to find any results.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Top comments" aren't just "comments that got the most upvotes". A system like that is inherently suceptible to [preferential attachment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Preferential_attachment), as you can see eg. on [reddit](https://i.redd.it/g3d1x1udi4ry.png).

Instead, YouTube tries to show you comments that they think aren't toxic and are relevant to you. This means in particular that:

- Your own comment(s) always gets shown to you at the very top.
- Comments from people you are subscribed to get sorted higher. (This was advertised as one of the main benefit when the system was changed when the Google+ integration happened)
- [Toxic comments](http://perspectiveapi.com/#/) get sorted lower.
- New comments get sorted higher, old ones lower.
- Likes get sorted higher, dislikes get sorted lower.
- There likely are *a lot* more factors playing into this - a person often participating in the community being sorted higher than a random person dropping in wouldn't be too far fetched of a metric being used.

Overall, as long as YouTube doesn't say how their comment algorithm works, we won't know whether certain users get preferred for everyone.

Comment: dislikes on comments do not work, just wanted to note that out and thank you

Comment: Dislikes on comments don't affect the like counter, but they still are used to sort the comments.

Comment: if you refresh the page the dislike is gone from the comment you disliked, it doesn't work, that's for sure

Comment: It doesn't have to store the event, it can just measure how many people actually click on it. Which they do as employees repeatedly stated on reddit's r/youtube, as well as in this blog post:
`First off, we’ve improved the ranking system that reduces the visibility of junk comments. It’s working—the rate of dislikes on comments has dropped by more than 35 percent across YouTube.` -- https://youtube-creators.googleblog.com/2015/07/keeping-conversation-going.html

Comment: but that was way back in 2015, until they used the google+ system, google plus has no dislike.

Comment: Google+ integration happened in December 2013.

Comment: `Your own comment(s) always gets shown to you at the very top.` Not always. They seem to get shown at the top for some time, then later on, they get buried accordingly, like other comments. I've seen old videos where my comment was no longer at the top. Regarding dislikes, Google records dislikes on comments in their database, they just refuse to show anyone. Now they want to do the same with dislikes on videos.  They want themselves to have all the data, but not anyone else. ¬_¬

Answer (score 0):

Since I am personally a Youtuber, I noticed that when you upload a video there are options for comments such as: newest first, oldest first or most helpful. There are even options for users to pay money to make their comment appear on top.
**Conclusion:** The order of the comments on a Youtube video pretty much depends on the user who uploaded it.
I hope this helped you answer this question

Answer (score -1):

On a lot of game theory channels that go into the lore of video game worlds a lot of LOL type comments get upvoted but if you actually ask a question about the world you get ignored.  I find it ironic and I think that Youtube does promote certain comments to keep people divided.

Google is being sued by a lot of people now and are in deep trouble from admitting to do bad things.  Here is a video that may answer this question better then any of these *including mine*.  https://duckduckgo.com/?q=Google+caught+manipulating+2020+election+video&t=h_&ia=web&iai=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com%2Fwatch%3Fv%3D89RdFhwv2oI&pn=1

The news when it was broke went WILD and it wasn't this hard but now you can't find the actual  videos. The videos on this search result is the 'short' version. Literally the next day the full video was removed everywhere but I caught snippets of it that wasn't a news report talking about it.

Now you just get news talking about whatever it is you search for.